# Array printing method giving exception

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a method for printing out the contents of an array, but when I run it it gives an error. Can you take a look at my code? I can't find the problem

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to get the length of the array is arr.length, not arr.length()

Answer (score 3):

`length` is a field in arrays, not a method. Remove the parenthesis:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```